# How to plot discrete density function in R

Tags: r

graph "density function" if I have for example X = 12, 13, 14 with probabilities of 0.25, 0.25, 0.50, all on the same graph? each number has the mentioned probability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  Many ways to do this.  `barplot()` is one:

```
dat <- data.frame(
    x = 12:14,
    p = c(0.25, 0.25, 0.5)
)

barplot(p~x, data=dat)
```

Comment: I fixed the numbers, sorry.

Comment: exist the possibility with dbinom ? using the syntax x n p

Comment: You don't need `dbinom()` because you already know the probabilities (0.25, 0.25, 0.5).  But if you must, then `dbinom(x=1, size=1, p=c(0.25, 0.25, 0.5))`.

Comment: unfortunately there are people deleting my content. I don't understand how it is possible that they are answering so many homework questions and deleting mine. Can you help me with other questions, let me know how?

Comment: unfortunately there are people deleting my content. I don't understand how it is possible that they are answering so many homework questions and deleting mine. Can you help me with other questions, let me know how?

Comment: Did you read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)?  Usually, you can get help with homework here on SO *but only if* you show what you've tried so far and where you are getting stuck.  Posting your homework question with no attempt to answer it will usually get the post downvoted and ultimately deleted.